# Syntax for mapply vs for loop

Tags: r, loops, mapply

My goal is to take a data set, 1. subset it and 2. print to .csv files

Example data

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- iris
```

Method to subset data:

```
z <- (split(mydata, (as.numeric(rownames(mydata))-1) %/% 50))
str(z)
```

I'm trying to use mapply and I can't get the syntax right.

```
mapply(write_csv(z, paste0(z,"file.csv"), col_names = FALSE)
```

If I were to code it with a for loop here's how I'd do it:

```
for(i in names(z)){
  write_csv(z[[i]], paste0(i,"file.csv"), col_names = FALSE)
}
```

How would I go about using `mapply`?

Comment: you want sapply or lapply (same result for your purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wth sapply this should work:

```
sapply(names(z),function(x){write_csv(z[[x]],paste0(x,"file.csv"), col_names = FALSE))
```

with mapply it would work this way

```
mapply(function(x,y){write_csv(x,paste0(y,"file.csv"), col_names = FALSE)},z,names(z))
```

Comment: I couldn't get `sapply` to work but `mapply` worked perfectly.